# I/O Error with deleting a character from file

Tags: python-2.7, io

Hi please I want to delete the last character in a file I am writing to with this code and I get an error. Here is my code:

```
with open("output.txt", 'rb+') as f:
    f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
    f.truncate()
```

and the error

```
f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
(-43501.4, -3763303)
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I get this despite using the import os. Please how can I fix this, or are there other ways to delete the character. I use a windows 7 OS and Python 2.7 thank you

Comment: Sounds like your file is empty.

Comment: @ Martijn but the file gets written despite the error statement

Comment: Sure, you opened the file for reading and writing, that creates the file. But if it is newly created and empty, you cannot seek back from the end.

Comment: Except that `'rb+'` does not create the file; so the file already existed.

Comment: @Ok I get your point, but is there any other way to get that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martijn's correct that you can't seek from the end of an empty file, and a work-around is not to use seek, but supply the `size` argument to `truncate`, eg:

```
import os

with open('testing.txt', 'rb+') as f:
    f.truncate(max(0, os.path.getsize(f.name) - 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your file is empty; you cannot seek beyond the start of the file.